# Unable to print SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services in IE8

Tags: sql, sql-server, internet-explorer-8, sql-server-2014

My company has upgraded all of its client databases from sQL Server 2008 to 2014 and we have now found that none of our clients are able to print the reporting services reports in IE8. Unfortunately we are required to support the legacy app but I have been unable to find a resolution. When clicking on the print button it appears to install the activex control but I then get the error, "Printing is not available. Verify that ActiveX is enabled, or try using Internet Explorer for the desktop."

After reviewing all articles I can find on the specified error I found that the recommendation was to "Enable download for ActiveX client print control" I have verified all setting on the SQL server are correct and that the ActiveX is enabled on the server but it is still not working. I have tried uninstalling the ActiveX control for the local client machine and letting the server re-install it but still I am unable to print.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: have you considered a newer version of ie?

Comment: ie 8 is what... Windows 7 or is this still XP? After uninstalling the RSClientPrint ActiveX Control and getting the fresh version from the server, are you doing this as an administrator? What if you uninstall, reboot the desktop and then try accepting the updated control?

Comment: Old but possibly still relevant notes from my slog through troubleshooting [Unable to load client print control](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/02/unable-to-load-client-print-control.html)

Comment: I would love to upgrade all my client computers to a newer version of IE but unfortunately they are not my computers and they are running legacy programs that do not allow them to upgrade. I have tried uninstalling the old RSClientPrint ActiveX Control and allowing the new one to install but it just does not install even though I am logged into the machine as administrator. When you are refering to your other article is this something I need to do on the server or workstation.

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution for **POSReady 2009 / Windows XP** clients and **SSRS 2014**.
The issue was solve by installing the **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package** on the clients.

After this the clients could install the Active-X component and the error message "Printing not available" disappeared and the printer selection appeared